# mac 10.13 askForPassword

Tags: bash, shell, applescript

In MacOS 10.13, I want to disable require password on awake of screen saver by terminal.
I try to use

```
defaults write screensaver.plist askForPassword -bool no
```

but it does not work.

Comment: StackOverflow is a site related to programming issues. I suggest you to take a look at [Superuser website](https://superuser.com)

Comment: @Cid This can be regarded as a programming issue as it’s a line of code entered into a terminal with the expectation that it will issue a command to the computer and produce the desired result.  Had the code sample here been given in the context of a larger shell script, you likely wouldn’t take issue with it.  Therefore, this can be seen as one line of code of a larger script, where this has been definitively seen to be the problem-causing line.  I’m going to +1 this question to help ratify its position on Stackoverflow.

Comment: @CJK I understand this point of view, but he might get more help on SU. BTW I didn't downvoted (and usually rarely do)

Answer (score 1):

Try using this code:

```
sudo osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to set require password to wake of security preferences to false'
```

Comment: Didn't work on my system: **_System info:_** _AppleScript version_: "2.7", _system version_: "10.13.4"

Comment: Have you tried going into System Preferences > Security and Privacy and disabling require password after 5 seconds to never?

Comment: That isn't an option. To disable the `Require password` option altogether via _System Preferences_, one would uncheck the checkbox.  Currently, it is checked (because the goal is to turn it off programmatically), and its time delay in the drop-down list is set to `Immediately`.

Comment: @Rishi Serumadar,Thank you for your answer, but it doesn't work, maybe it worked in a pre-10.13 version.。